# Jasmine testing that a subclass object has been called through a Knockout subscribe

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, knockout.js, jasmine

I've got a few things interacting here, and they aren't interacting well.

I have a base class:

```
    var ObjOne = (function() {
        return function() {
            var self = this;
            self.propertyOne = ko.observable(1);
            self.observable = ko.observable(1);

            self.observable.subscribe(function(newValue) {
                self.propertyOne(newValue);
            });
        };
    } ());
```

It has two Knockout observables, and defines a subscribe on one of them that updates the other.

I have a "subclass", extended with jQuery.extend:

```
    var ObjTwo = (function() {
        return function() {
            this.base = new ObjOne();
            $.extend(this, this.base);
        };
    } ());
```

And I have a Jasmine test, which is attempting to ask the question "when I update observable, is propertyOne called?"

```
it('Test fails to call the correct propertyOne', function() {
    var obj = new ObjTwo();
    spyOn(obj, 'propertyOne').andCallThrough();

    obj.observable(2);

    expect(obj.propertyOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(obj.propertyOne()).toBe(2);
});
```

This fails with "Expected spy propertyOne to have been called.". When I debug, the observable is updated properly. In the actual system, it works fine (as well, even the test "is propertyOne equal to 2?" passes. When I debug into the subscribe function, self.propertyOne is not a spy, but in the test, it is.

I have a solution, but it isn't great:

```
 it('Test calls the base propertyOne', function() {
    var obj = new ObjTwo();
    spyOn(obj.base, 'propertyOne').andCallThrough();

    obj.observable(2);

    expect(obj.base.propertyOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(obj.propertyOne()).toBe(2);
});
```

Note the **.base** added to the two lines. I don't like that I've had to expose the base class, or had to touch it's properties in order to make the test run.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DrrW/23/. The question is - is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know Knockout and its conventions, but I am sure that you misuse Jasmine. `it(...)` should sound like a meaningful sentence. Also, it depends on the whole context, but mocking the base module might be the way to go.

Comment: The cooked up example may not have the same title as the actual code :). We started out by _testing_ the base module, but that didn't feel right. Mocking the base might be a decent thought though...in my example we aren't testing anything in the "super class", so why are we writing tests against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call `$.extend(this, this.base);` your object basically looks like:

```
{
    base: {
        propertyOne: ko.observable(1),
        observable: ko.observable(1)
    },
    propertyOne: base.propertyOne,
    observable: base.observable
}
```

When you do a `spyOn` for `propertyOne` it replaces it with a wrapper. However, the subscription is set between the actual observables and would not have any way to call the wrapper.

If you do not want to access `base`, then I would just remove the test that the observable was called. Checking that the value is correct seems sufficient.

Otherwise, you would probably be better off mixing in `ObjOne` by calling its constructor with the new object's `this` like:

```
var ObjTwo = (function() {
    return function() {
        ObjOne.call(this);
    };
} ());
```

Then, the test would be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/z2GU3/

Comment: I feel like my question has been answered by The Knockout Celebrity. You are right in this case, where checking for the value change is good enough, but we've learned an awful lot over the last 8 months about "taking things for granted" and I wanted to not start this subclassing thing by having a potential issue with testing. :) Apparently your answer solves some of my co-workers other issues as well. Thanks!